# How to connect a database on local server with wordpress site?

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a problem with database connection on local server. I already have a database developed in MySQL. But when I import the database from localhost to wordpress It doesnt show up with anything.

Comment: Questions about wordpress site administration do not belong on Stack Overflow.  They should be posted to wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a black screen when you try to access the site, or do you see an "error establishing a database connection" message?

At the very least, when you move a Wordpress site, you need to update two entries in the `wp_options` table of the database - `siteurl` and `home`. These are typically options 1 & 2, and in most cases should just reflect the URL for your site.

Of course you also need to update your `wp-config.php` file in the root directory with the updated database name/username/password, if relevant.

Answer (score 0):

After uploading your local database to server.

change **wp-config.php** from root of directory with db name, username & password.

then use below query

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

**Old domain means your local server path.
New domain means your server path where you want to live.**

Answer (score -1):

You mean about the migration process. I think if I understsnd you correctly you must change the paths in the exported database. But you can use the plugin Duplicator in local machine , this produce 2 file, you must upload the files to hosting company and migrate your site. 
Another plugin is 
https://el.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/ this is the link in Greek, plugin name is all-in-one-wp-migrtaion , you must store both to source and destination and import to destination the exported file from source (must be < 500mb)
another way is to open your sql export with notepad++ and change the paths